# How To Get The Text Inside The Quotation Marks Using RegEx

Tags: regex

I have a random generated text with quotation marks and inside it there has randomally generated words with numbers combined

This what i have done so far:

```
(?<!["])(")\w+
```

https://regex101.com/r/aIXAnk/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use capturing groups, you can do this:

```
(?<=["])\w+?(?=["])
```

It matches a string with a double quote in front of it and a quote behind it.

Also, it's better to use the `?` to make it not match more than you want.

**Please note that if you have 3 or more quotation marks it may return unexpected results.**

The best way is to use capturing groups like that:

```
"(\w+?)"
```

and grab the content by capturing group 1.